# Problem using WebBrowser control as editor

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, webbrowser-control, designmode

I am currently working on a project where I am using a WebBrowser control as an editor. I have design mode turned on and it seems to be working. The issue im having is when I try to save the Document and load another it pops up the "This document has been modified." message. What I am trying to do is as simple as this

```
if (frontPage)
{
    frontPage = false;
    frontContent = webEditor.DocumentText;
    webEditor.DocumentText = backContent;
}
else
{
    frontPage = true;
    backContent = webEditor.DocumentText;
    webEditor.DocumentText = frontContent;
}
```

Like I said everytime I enter some text and run this code it just pops up a message saying its been modified and asks if I want to save. How can I get around this?

Comment: C# does not have a web browser control. Did you mean the WinForms WebBrowser Control?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The way Windows Forms load a document stream (used by the DocumentText property) is to navigate away to about:blank, which triggers the document modified message, then load the stream in its DocumentComplete event handler.

Since you already have a document, you can skip the navigation and load the stream into the  existing document directly via its IPersistStreamInit interface like Windows Forms does in its DocumentComplete event handler.

Answer (score 2):

You should create the following function:

```
void ChangeAllowWebBrowserDrop() { webBrowser.AllowWebBrowserDrop = !webBrowser.AllowWebBrowserDrop; }
```

It should be called every time before you change DocumentText.

Answer (score 1):

You could set

```
BodyHtml.
```

Like this:

```
string newHTMLString="some html";
webBrowser1.Document.Body.InnerHtml = newHTMLString;
```

Worked for me .

Answer (score 1):

You should create the following function:

```
void ChangeAllowWebBrowserDrop() {
    webBrowser.AllowWebBrowserDrop = !webBrowser.AllowWebBrowserDrop;
}
```

It should be called every time before you change `DocumentText`.

Answer (score 1):

better solution is to write empty string before you actually assign your html code:
WebBrowser1.Document.Write(string.Empty);
WebBrowser1.DocumentText = "your code";

Answer (score 1):

I have solved this problem so:

```
browser.Document.Write(string.Empty);  
browser.DocumentText="Your html code";
```

This is from this link:
http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/3a9c1965-8559-4972-95e1-da0e86cf87bb/webbrowser-strange-problem

Answer (score 0):

Try this `webEditor.ScriptErrorsSuppressed = true;`

Make sure you have disabled Script Debugging in IE in case you've turned it on.